# The "run-one" command does not work if sub-script is ran in background

Tags: bash

I use [run-one](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/run-one.1.html) command to run `test.sh`, and ensure that only one instance of it runs at a time.  `test.sh` sometimes starts another long running script called `execute.sh` with this command:  `setsid execute.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &` (with a proper path), and `test.sh` quits right away.

The problem is that for some reason, run-one continues to think that `test.sh` is still running, just because `execute.sh` is still running. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not instead use a lock file (e.g. `/var/lock/subsys/test`), and then at the start of the script either create a lock file and run, or exit if the file exists? Sounds simpler than trying to wrap everything in another command when you're using subshells etc...

Then at the end of the script you just need to remove the lock file?

Comment: I tried it for a bit, but ran into even more issues. I seems that using a well defined command that does exactly the needed task is more appropriate that hacking it yourself. I just need to start an unattached sub-process. Thx!